# Offline routing Mapbox dataset

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to obtain a projected dataset which has all streets and addresses.

I used OSMNx to get the a shapefile with all streets. However  unlike Mapbox , i can not look up a street via address . Is there a way to obtain the address for each street?

Can i download a shapefile from Mapbox with the address attribute?

Answer (score 1):

This is not available from Mapbox, however you can use the [Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/) Mapbox offers and implement it into your project.